# Placeholder Text Not Fitting Input Area

Tags: css, forms, placeholder

I'm having a hard time finding help for this question, hope that asking is helpful for other beginners trying to figure this out.

My placeholder text isn't fitting in the input area. Padding doesn't seem to be doing the trick, either (I took out the padding I had in the code as it wasn't working).

**html**

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="email">
</form>
```

**css**

```
form {
margin:60px auto;
width:350px;
}

input[type='text'] {
width:300px;
height:40px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;  
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size:18px; 
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9cWtJ/  Fits fine .... you must be more specific when you describe the problem.  What's wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be fitting when I look at it in Chrome - the placeholder text "email" is completely cut in half.

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle I created?  Works fine for me in Chrome.  Must be something else interfering with your code.  It would help us help you if you could create your own fiddle which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yep, viewed the fiddle and it was cut-off on my end. Tried it here: jsfiddle.net/eN2Nr

Comment: Is it a requirement that the placeholder text be larger than the input text?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird It's not at all and you asking that just made me realize that my not including a size for the input text was messing things up - I added code to make the text size the same and it works fine now - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text that the user is inputting to be the same size as the placeholder, then add that size to the input

```
input[type='text'] {
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eN2Nr/2/